# Jquery not working globally, after injecting it from Webpack, in a React app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to figure out what's going on exactly, with usage of Jquery through the the ProvidePlugin functionality of Webpack. I have this setup:

```
plugins: [
  CSSExtract,
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'

  })
```

When i console.log "$" anywhere in my React application, it clearly shows that Jquery is present. Yet Bootstrap, **which i'm loading externally from a script tag**, gives me this error:

> ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Which of course implies, that Jquery isn't present. I know very little about all this, but from what i understand, this is some kind of scoping problem.

The reason i'm loading "normal" bootstrap is because i'm using some HTML template, which has nothing to do with react.

Can some one clarify, how come this Jquery Webpack plugin doesn't make it available globally?

What would be correct approach, to make this bootstrap functionality work? Loading Jquery again from a script tag, seems totally unnecessary and problematic to me.

EDIT: ok, i realized my mistake, i should've loaded bootstrap from a React component, just like any other 3rd party module. Still, i would be happy to hear some simple technical explanation, as to why Jquery wasn't available to the externally loaded bootstrap. I know it's "intuitive", but i wouldn't be able to explain exactly why, with my limited knowledge.

Another edit: is it because the bundle.js is loaded after the jquery and bootstrap scripts?

Comment: Can you provide the entire error message, or is this all of it? It says that it tries to read "fn" as a member of another object, so it would be interesting to see on which object it tries to read "fn" from.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:68
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ util.js:68
(anonymous) @ util.js:10
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6 ...nothing helpful :D

Comment: Are you loading bootstrap before your bundle?

Comment: yeah..exactly..and this is what i realized, just before your comment :D I'm used to loading the custom JS after jquery and bootstrap, like in the old pre-React days...